# Link direcionando de forma errada com htacess

Tags: htaccess

Estou utilizando a seguinte estrutura em endereços/links para url amigável em fixos da minha página:

```
RewriteRule ^teste(.*)$ teste.php
```

Então, meu endereço fica da seguinte forma: `www.site.com/teste`
Acontece que se o usuario digitar a palavra teste junto de outro termo, o site encontra do mesmo jeito, sendo que deveria mandar para a pagina de erro 404..
Ex: www.site.com/teste123
Com o link acima digitado, ele redireciona para a pagina de teste normalmente..

Comment: queres que a regex só apanhe se fôr `teste/` é isso? nesse caso testa `^teste\/(.*)$`

Comment: RewriteRule ^dicionario\/(.*)$ dicionario.php <- Assim ficou minha url. Porém, agora o servidor não encontra nada e envia para o erro 404..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quiser que só funcione `teste`, não pode ter o `.*`.

```
RewriteRule ^teste$ teste.php
```

Se quiser que o URL aceite mais coisas, separadas por barras, pode usar assim:

```
RewriteRule ^teste(/.*)*$ teste.php
```

Comment: Perfeita resposta, obrigado.
Tenho uma outra dúvida, outra regra mais complexa. Prefere que eu edite a pergunta para que veja melhor ou posso adicionar aqui nos comentarios mesmo? A dúvida é com a seguinte linha: RewriteRule ^teste-([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ teste.php?slug=$1 [NC]

Comment: Isso seria o caso de pergunta separada, pois muda o problema. Na verdade, acho que isso aí já tem até resposta no site, pesquise por URL amigável, ou URLS amigáveis. Mas eu acho que compensa você separar o slug com barra normal, e não com hifen, assim pode separar o script do slug/ID do post..

Comment: É que no caso eu gostaria de mostrar a categoria, e isso funciona perfeitamente com /, o unico problema é que quando utilizo, meu css desconfigura, principalmente com imagens..

Comment: Isso eu respondi esses dias. O problema é o URL do css, se começar por barra na hora de chamar, resolve. Chame seu CSS assim: `src="/css/meuscript.css"` e não `src="css/meusscripts.css"`. Se puser a barra no começo, pode chamar de qq pagina do site que funciona.

Comment: Desculpe. Pra falar a verdade o que está desconfigurando não é o css, são as imagens, elas não sao encontradas, porque a barra está fazendo com que pareça que o arquivo está em outro diretorio, e como o link é relativo o problema ocorre. o link fica assim: http://localhost/site/artigo/titulo-de-teste

Comment: Thiago, mesma coisa. Não faça relativo pra não dar dor de cabeça. Ou se precisar ser relativo, basta acrescentar um ../ antes. Mas se puder por absoluto, facilita sua vida.

Comment: Tudo bem, desculpe-me a ignorância. Uma dúvida: se eu usar todos os links do meu site de forma absoluta, quando estiver no servidor remoto irá atrasar o carregamento da página? como se fosse uma nova requisição de URL?

Comment: Não muda nada, pois a requisição é sempre absoluta. Aliás, se vc fizer relativa, quem converte para absoluta é o próprio navegador. Uma requisição HTTP sempre tem o formato GET /caminho/absoluto. O resto é sempre processado pelo navegador para virar absoluto. Não se preocupe com ignorância. Quem pergunta, é "ignorante" só na hora e aprende (assim como todo mundo antes de aprender). Quem não pergunta é que corre o risco de ser ignorante pra sempre ;)

Comment: Isso é uma coisa pessoal, mas eu geralmente crio uma pasta /assets/ na raiz, e ponho tudo que é do layout do site (imagens, logos, css) em subpastas (pode ser numa CDN tambem). O que é imagem de conteúdo (matérias, etc) nao vai no assets, vai em /images/ e assim vai. Aí fica mais fácil de organizar. Mas isso depende do projeto. O importante é o time que está desenvolvendo criar uma regra, e todo mundo seguir.

Comment: Entendi! A ideia é bastante interessante, talvez eu a implemente em futuros projetos. Outra coisa, agora que eu alterei o endereço relativo da imagem para absoluto, eu abri o link localhost/site/artigo/titulo-de-teste, e ao tentar navegar por outro link, por exemplo a pagina de contato, ficou localhost/site/artigo/contato.. Isso acontece porque os endereços estão relativos? Fiz um teste e alterei a regex "agenda" para: "localhost/site/agenda" e funcionou, ja as outras ficaram com /artigo/localizacao"